# Evaluate line integral over a path

Tags: calculus, integration

All our class notes are really basic questions on this topic where we're just given an equation and $2$-dimensional coordinates & I can do those fine but I'm just a bit confused where to start or the method for this type of question.

I've attempted it by using parametrisation but I think I've confused myself more :( I'm not looking for the exact solution just some tips on where to start would be great!!

Thanks in advance

(PS sorry for the poor mathematical formatting but I'm posting from my phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F$ is a scalar function?

leg 1:
$r = (t,0,0)\\
\frac {dr}{dt} = (1,0,0)\\ 
||dr|| = dt$

$\int_0^{\alpha} (e^{-t}+e^0 + e^0) dt$

leg 2:
$r = (\alpha,t,0)\\
\frac {dr}{dt} = (0,1,0)\\ 
||dr|| = dt$

$\int_0^{\beta} (e^{-\alpha}+e^{-t} + e^0) dt$

etc.

Comment: so would the answer end up being e^−α+e^−β+e^−γ+1
? Not sure if I've done this correctly!! @Doug

Comment: That doesn't look right.  The $1^{st}$ leg $= (1-e^{-\alpha}) + 2\alpha $,  The $2^{nd}$ leg $= (1-e^{-\beta}) + \beta (e^{\alpha} + 1)$

Comment: for the 1st leg I get as far as (1-e^-alpha) but I can't understand where the 2alpha comes from?

Comment: $\int_0^{\alpha} e^{-t} + 2 dt = -e^t + 2 t |_0^{\alpha} = e^0 - e^{-\alpha} + 2\alpha.$

Comment: Hoping I've done the 3rd leg correctly: $(e^(-\beta) + e^(-\alpha)) \gamma - (e^(-\gamma) -1)$

Comment: That looks right.

Comment: so I just add the 3 legs together now right?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

When you are doing the leg from $(\alpha,0,0)$ to $(\alpha,\beta,0)$, fix the variable $x$ in your expression as the constant $\alpha$ and do the integral from $y=0$ to $y=\beta$.

When you are moving in the $x$ direction, $y$ and $z$ are treated as constants, and so forth.